# Doctrine 2 Entity Column Method Name

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to define the method name manuall instead of the generated ones?

Lets show an example on the following entity (with auto generated methods from doctrine):

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\EntityRepository\Zone")
 * @ORM\Table(name="zones")
 *
 */
class Zone
{
    /**
     * @var ZoneRecordNS[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ZoneRecordNS", mappedBy="zone", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"ownername" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $recordsns;

    /**
     * Get recordsns
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getRecordsns()
    {
        return $this->recordsns;
    }

    /**
     * Add recordsn
     *
     * @param \Application\Entity\ZoneRecordNS $recordsn
     *
     * @return Zone
     */
    public function addRecordsn(\Application\Entity\ZoneRecordNS $recordsn)
    {
        $this->recordsns[] = $recordsn;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove recordsn
     *
     * @param \Application\Entity\ZoneRecordNS $recordsn
     */
    public function removeRecordsn(\Application\Entity\ZoneRecordNS $recordsn)
    {
        $this->recordsns->removeElement($recordsn);
    }
}
```

Doctrine 2 writes the method "addRecordsn", but i would like to have it named "addRecordNS".

If i rewrite the autogenerated methods and force a "orm:generate-entities --generate-methods=1", doctrine will recreate the the autogenerated methods again..

Is it possible to create a annotation, or something other, to force doctrine to use the user-written methods instead of the auto generated ones?

**Update**
i tried renaming also now.

with "$recordNS":

```
/**
 * @var ZoneRecordNS[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ZoneRecordNS", mappedBy="zone", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"ownername" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $recordNS;

/**
 * Add recordN
 *
 * @param \Application\Entity\ZoneRecordNS $recordN
 *
 * @return Zone
 */
public function addRecordN(\Application\Entity\ZoneRecordNS $recordN)
{
    $this->recordNS[] = $recordN;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove recordN
 *
 * @param \Application\Entity\ZoneRecordNS $recordN
 */
public function removeRecordN(\Application\Entity\ZoneRecordNS $recordN)
{
    $this->recordNS->removeElement($recordN);
}

/**
 * Get recordNS
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getRecordNS()
{
    return $this->recordNS;
}
```

and with "$recordNSs":

```
/**
 * @var ZoneRecordNS[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ZoneRecordNS", mappedBy="zone", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"ownername" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $recordNSs;

/**
 * Add recordNSs
 *
 * @param \Application\Entity\ZoneRecordNS $recordNSs
 *
 * @return Zone
 */
public function addRecordNSs(\Application\Entity\ZoneRecordNS $recordNSs)
{
    $this->recordNSs[] = $recordNSs;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove recordNSs
 *
 * @param \Application\Entity\ZoneRecordNS $recordNSs
 */
public function removeRecordNSs(\Application\Entity\ZoneRecordNS $recordNSs)
{
    $this->recordNSs->removeElement($recordNSs);
}

/**
 * Get recordNSs
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getRecordNSs()
{
    return $this->recordNSs;
}
```

so it seems not possible in my variable name delaration to get correct human readable method names :-(.

sadly there is also no annotation to force a manual typed method name.

Comment: Did you try with renaming the property to `$recordsNS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine uses **[a `singularize` method](https://github.com/doctrine/inflector/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Inflector/Inflector.php#L433)** to get the method names from your property name. So the property name is a base for the method names. So if you want NS with capitalized characters you should also write your property name like that. The additional 's' makes it plural and is stripped for a single element. This is why you get `addRecordsn` and not what you want `addRecordns` (check the order of `s`and `n`)

```
protected $recordNSs;
```

will give you `addRecordNS` and `removeRecordNS`

or use

```
protected $records;
```

which will give you `addRecord` and `removeRecord`

or use

```
protected $NSRecords;
```

which will give you `addNSRecord` and `removeNSRecord`

Comment: i have updated my question, just tested the cases. it seems right now not possible with my variable name declaration - thanks for clearing this anyway

Comment: @exxecc I bet when you use  `$NSRecords` it will work. But maybe that is not the name for the collection you want...

Comment: @exxecc You can make [an issue on `GitHub` in the doctrine repository](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2) with a request to add your case to the `Inflector` class.

Comment: for the next projects i will remind that of cource. in the actual project im too far to change all the names. i will create an issue later, good idea. thanks for your time!